# Python package: errors "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" & "failed with exit code 2"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-packaging, windows-build-tools

I'm trying to install a package on python (pip install basedosdados -U) and I get the following message: error:

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual
C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.mirosoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

After installing it and ticking this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwdvU.png) (as suggested by another thread I read), I now get the following error message:

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot!

I tried many things, just installing it without ticking the box previously mentioned also does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`? There seems to be no accurate solution to this problem. We can only take chances.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it also did not work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the `whl` instead of the `tar.gz`?
A `whl` is the "compiled" finished version of the package, so it should be able not to try to build it at all.

You can use `pip install basedosdados -U --prefer-binary` or just manually installing from `pypi`

Comment: Hi Barak, when running pip install basedosdados -U --prefer-binary I get the same  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2"

Comment: did you try to install the wheel as well?

Comment: sorry, I have got no experience with Python nor the Command Prompt. Could you elaborate on how i could install the wheel? Is it using the Command Prompt?

Comment: I believe to have installed wheel ( pip install whl). Afterwards I ran the code again and got the same error:                                           
command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas Failed to build pandas ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have encountered similar problems. The solution is to install 64-bit pandas instead of 32-bit.

You can read [the installation page](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files) and select the appropriate version to install.